# Trouble centering background image

Tags: html, css, background, center

I'm having problems centering the background image within a certain div. I'm using the following code for CSS:

```
.background3 {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(86, 71, 71, 0.56), rgba(86, 71, 71, 0.56)), url(img/kitpage.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

I've tinkered and tried, but to no avail. I'm pretty sure it's an easy answer, and thank you all in advance for your help and advice.

A screenshot of the problem is attached below

[image]

Comment: instead of 50% 50% try center center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in your CSS:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for the delay in getting back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use background position property e.g:

```
.background3 {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-position:20% 20%; // Margin background from top and left
}
```

You can adjust margin as you need  but it's not a good way. If you want more proper way then try this:

```
.background3 {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size:auto 100%;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for the delay in getting back to you.